# Из-за чего прерывается событие? (Qt, C++)

Tags: c++, qt

Приветствую. Цель такая: пользователь тащит кнопку (событие `mouseMoveEvent`), она отделяется от родительского виджета(окна), становится отдельным окном и продолжает двигаться вслед за курсором мыши. Вот мой код:

```
class QPushButtonn: public QPushButton{
    public:
    QPushButtonn(QWidget * parent = nullptr):QPushButton(parent){}
    QPoint Position;
    virtual void QPushButtonn::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* pe)
    {
        Position = pe->globalPos()-this->pos();
    }
    virtual void QPushButtonn::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* pe)
    {
        if (this->parent() != nullptr) {
            QPoint globPos = this->mapToGlobal(this->pos());
            QPoint p = this->parentWidget()->pos();
            this->setParent(nullptr);
            move(globPos-(globPos-p));
            this->show();
        }
        else
        {
            move(pe->globalPos() - Position);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();
    window->resize(336, 227);
    window->show();
    QPushButtonn bbbtn(window);
    bbbtn.resize(100, 100);
    bbbtn.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Это частично работает(кнопка отделяется от родителя и правильно позиционируется), но в момент когда кнопка стала окном, она перестает перетаскиваться(останавливается на месте) и для того, чтобы можно было ее перемещать, нужно заново по ней нажать и потянуть. То есть событие прерывается. Как можно избежать такого поведения?

**P.S.** Я пробовал много методов, в частности, `setFocus();`, `activateWindow` и другие, но событие все равно прерывается, после того, как кнопка становится окном.

Comment: А вам точно надо тягать кнопку имнно таким образом? Посмотрите в документации [`Draggable Text Example`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-draganddrop-draggabletext-example.html). Может оно вам подойдет

Comment: Попробуйте в вашем обработчике `mouseMoveEvent` прервать дальнейшее распространение события: `event->accept();`.

Comment: @aleks.andr, добавление `accept()` никак не повлияло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы кнопка продолжала двигаться вслед за курсором, даже после создания нового окна, нужно использовать метод `grabMouse();`.

В конец условия `if (this->parent() != nullptr)` необходимо добавить 2 строки:

```
this->grabMouse(); //Для захвата мыши
QPushButtonn::mousePressEvent(pe); //Для обновления переменной Position и правильного позиционирования
```

Также нужно переопределить событие `mouseReleaseEvent`:

```
virtual void QPushButtonn::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* pe)
{
    this->releaseMouse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых прошу рассмотреть вариант с драгэндробопом. Если он вас не устроит то предложу второй вариант решения. А именно, разработайте специальное окно для перетаскивания которое будет:

- настоящим окном, то есть для отображения ему не должен требоваться родитель в отличие от кнопки, например;
- окно для перетаскивания должно уметь собственно перетаскиваться везде и как вам нужно;
- должно уметь нести на себе нужные виджеты.

Когда вам нужно будет переместить виджет сразу создавайте окно для перетаскивания и помещайте на него виджет.

Comment: Вообще, я хочу сделать так: тащим кнопку - она становится окном, тащим ее обратно, она становится внутрь родительского окна(в изначальное положение). Так `Drag` - это ведь и есть `mouseMoveEvent`. У меня проблема с этим - кнопка перестает перетаскиваться после отделения, это - основной вопрос. А Drop я собираюсь реализовать так: определенной области главного окна сделать `setAcessDrops()` и при вхождении туда виджета кнопки назначать ей родителя.